# Ghost Blog: Google Compute Engine - unexpectedly closed the connection

Tags: server, google-cloud-platform, connection, google-compute-engine

I started a Ghost blog on Google's Compute Engine following this guide [here](https://www.andersontech.consulting/getting-started-with-ghost-on-google-cloud/). I have enabled both HTTP and HTTPS traffic.

The issue is the famous "This site can't be reached ... unexpectedly closed the connection."

A few of my friends have reported the issue with accessing the blog through their wifi, but no issues with 4G on their phones. I am able to reproduce the issue through my VPN, NordVPN. If I access the external IP address directly, I am able to get to the Nginx welcome page.

Are there firewall changes I need to make to allow these connections? I don't see why I am able to access it just fine on my wifi and they are not able to. Thank you for your help!

```
Machine type: f1-micro (1 vCPU, 0.6 GB memory)
CPU platform: Intel Haswell
Zone: us-east1-b
```

`gcloud compute firewall-rules list` on the instance results in the below:
[image]

Comment: Could you post the output of `gcloud compute firewall-rules list` just to be sure?

Comment: @marcyb5st, I have edited the post to include the output and included some additional information

Comment: you're using the default firewall rules which are pretty lenient. I'm assuming you have the instance tagged properly for both HTTP and HTTPS under network tags?

Comment: Yes I do! I have a solution, it was a "@" record DNS issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for digging into this. This is a rookie mistake on my part. Godaddy came with 4 "@" records in my DNS and I only changed one of them to point to my external IP. Once I deleted the other 3 "@" records, everything worked just fine.